# Creating a function to do what the builtin function "isdigit" does

Tags: python, string, function, python-2.7, if-statement

```
def my_isdigit(str):
    if digit in str >0 and str is int:
        print "True"
    else:
        print "False"
```

I am trying to create a function that does what `isdigit` does i.e. returns true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise.  Every time I try to use this it tells me "digit" is not defined.  I am confused as to what it is asking me to change...  Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The function looks at each character and only returns `True` if all are digits:

```
digits = '0123456789'

def isdigit(inputstring):
    if not inputstring: return False
    for char in inputstring:
        if char not in digits:
            return False
    return True
```

Or make use of string comparisons:

```
def isdigit(inputstring):
    if not inputstring: return False
    for char in inputstring:
        if not '0' <= char <= '9':
            return False
    return True
```

Your function is, unfortunately, way off. You don't define `digit`, nor do you loop over the characters of `str`. `int` is a type; strings (even individual characters) are *not* integers; and a string like `-42` can be converted to an integer but `'-42'.isdigit()` returns `False` because '-' is not a digit.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Would I have to define digits though?  Would 'int' not work?  I am trying to create a function to work exactly like the existing function isdigit...

Comment: @user2784808: `str is int` would check if `str` is a reference to the `int` type, which isn't related at all to whether it's a string containing only digits.

Comment: @user2784808: Rather than defining digits yourself, you could import them from the `string` module: `from string import digits` If you were worried about performance, testing membershipt in a `set` might be a little bit faster (but probably not by much since there are only 10 values).

Comment: @Blckknght: not importing from `string` was deliberate here. I doubt the OP is concerned about speed here. I'll settle for understanding what happens first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions

```
def my_isdigit(str):
    return re.search("[^\d]", str) is None
```

Since there's some questions here are some simple tests:

```
print my_isdigit("02211")
> True
print my_isdigit("022x01")
> False
print my_isdigit("a02201")
> False
```

Comment: It feels a little like using a cannon to shoot to a fly :)

Comment: That won't catch the "there is at least one character" condition, I think.

Comment: A working regex would be `^\d+$`. This matches that there is at least one digit character, and nothing else but digits between the start and the end of the text.

Comment: It would need to be changed to something like `return bool(re.search("^\d+$", str))` to really match the builtin `isdigit`

Comment: @SethMMorton there's no need to do do the bool(), but I agree that it could be better with "\d" instead of 0-9

Comment: I added the `bool` so that it wouldn't return an `re` match object.  Otherwise running `print` on something that matched would give `<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x2aaaae3df370>` instead of `True`.

Comment: @SethMMorton maybe you don't notice the `is None` at the end :)

Comment: Maybe you didn't notice in my example I removed `is None`.

Comment: oops! you are right :)

Answer (score 2):

@Martijn Pieters suggested how to fix your version; here for completeness is a more "pythonic" (and efficient) approach to the problem.

```
def my_isdigit(str):
    return all('0'<=c<='9' for c in str)
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `[]` inside of `all`. A generator expression works just as well as a list comprehension, and might not use as much memory (unlikely a problem in this situation, but a good idea in general).

Comment: The pythonic solution would be to use `.isdigit()` :-P I omitted this version because I didn't think the OP was up to learning how generator expressions work in addition.